# How to solve the "GLib-GObject-CRITICAL g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed" error?

Tags: c++, qt

I have developed a simple application (using QT) to record the video from laptop's camera. I've used the following classes:

```
 QCamera
 QCameraInfo
 QMediaRecorder
 QUrl
 QCameraViewfinder
 QCameraImageCapture
```

It works and it can show the video and I am able to still an image but, when I try to record a video using "QMediaRecorder" I face the following error:

Error message:

> (videoD:19102): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:01:07.717: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

The operation system is Ubuntu 18 and I have installed libpulse-dev.

Comment: I have the same problem but with nvidia deep stream5. Put a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312862/nvidia-deepstream-5-glib-gobject-critical-error