# Nvidia deepstream 5: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL error

Tags: nvidia-deepstream

I am trying to install deepstream-5 inside a docker container. I used a container with the following specs:
10.2-cudnn7-tensorrt7-devel-ubuntu18.04 (cuda 10.2.89, nccl 2.7.8, cudnn 7.6.5.32, tensorrt 7.0.0.11) from [Here](https://hub.docker.com/r/vistart/cuda). And python 3.6

After that, I installed deepstream-5 as described in their official site.

When I run one of their tests:

```
deepstream-app -c /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/source4_1080p_dec_infer-resnet_tracker_sgie_tiled_display_int8.txt
```

I get this error. I don't know how to fix it.
[image]

I tried to remove the cache as suggested in [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-create-render-bin-95-failed-to-create-sink-sub-bin-sink1/140263), now I have warnings beside the errors :D. I checked, and already have the two files that in the warning.
[image]

I asked on Nvidia-Forum. [Here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/glib-gobject-critical-error/156840).

Comment: What version of python do you have installed?

Comment: I am using python 3.6. But this is a C++ test. @Areg

Comment: Make sure `libtrtserver.so` is present.

Comment: How can I check @mibrahimy

Comment: Try `locate` or make sure you have all your dependencies set up.

Comment: I think I don't have it 
`find . -name "*libtrtserver*"` outputs nothing
But I doubt that I need it because I have downloaded the nvidia-deepstream-5 docker, it's working and it doesn't have this file. @mibrahimy

Comment: Make sure the docker contains the `libtrtserver`. The `find` command you are using will search in the current directory only I guess.

Comment: Okay. I used `dpkg -l | grep trt` and found `libgstrtspserver-1.0-0`. Didn't find `libtrtserver`